# Why won't my blender project export as a .FBX properly

Tags: export, unity, .fbx

[image: The FBX reimported back into blender]

This is what exports with the .fbx looks like when I import it into unity or back into blender. I would like to use this in unity but I have no clue how to. The second image is a picture of the model before I export it.
[image]